# How do you call a custom Lightning Component from inside a VF page?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, email-template

I have a lightning component which is a modal window which lets me choose an email template. I want it to be opened when I click a button on my VF page. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could make it open in a separate window with [lightning:isUrlAdderssable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation) or you can use [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm) to have it embedded in your page.

Comment: I made some use of the lighting:out. How to invoke the lightning component on the click of a button?

Comment: When using LightningOut you explicitly create the components you need using $Lightning.createComponent, and here you can define a [callback function invoked when the component is created](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_markup.htm), allowing you to access the component identity. You can store the identity for later use in JavaScript called from a button, for example to set the necessary attribute values on the component.

Comment: Thanks Phil! I will do the same.